# Restore modal on cancel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal, thats shown upon clicking a button. If I try to submit the form validates as illustrated. When I cancel then reopen the modal, I need to restore it as it was before validation. Is that possible ?

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far but didnt work at all:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQuery('#login-box').on('hidden', function () {
    jQuery.clearInput();
    jQuery('input, select').removeClass('error');
    jQuery('.control-group').removeClass('error');
    jQuery('label.error').remove();
 });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the modal

```
jQuery('#login-box').on('hidden', function () {
    jQuery(this).data('modal', null);
});
```

Comment: Your solution works well with existing code, it compliments it very well. Thanks